# how to test react-saga axios post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, chai, nock

I am learning how to test and using some examples as a guideline I am trying to mock a login post. The example used fetch for the http call but I using axios. This is the error I am getting

> Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

All of the answers to this error had to do with fetch, how do I do this with axios

./saga

```
const encoder = credentials => Object.keys(credentials).map(key => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(credentials[key])}`).join('&')

const postLogin = credentials => {
  credentials.grant_type = 'password'
  const payload = {
    method: 'post',
    headers: config.LOGIN_HEADERS,
    data: encoder(credentials),
    url: `${config.IDENTITY_URL}/Token`
  }
  return axios(payload)
}

function * loginRequest (action) {
  try {
    const res = yield call(postLogin, action.credentials)
    utils.storeSessionData(res.data)
    yield put({ type: types.LOGIN_SUCCESS, data: res.data })
  } catch (err) {
    yield put({ type: types.LOGIN_FAILURE, err })
  }
}

function * loginSaga () {
  yield takeLatest(types.LOGIN_REQUEST, loginRequest)
}

export default loginSaga
```

./login-test

```
const loginReply = {
  isAuthenticating: false,
  isAuthenticated: true,
  email: 'foo@yahoo.com',
  token: 'access-token',
  userId: '1234F56',
  name: 'Jane Doe',
  title: 'Tester',
  phoneNumber: '123-456-7890',
  picture: 'pic-url',
  marketIds: [1, 2, 3]
}

describe('login-saga', () => {
  it('login identity user', async (done) => {
    // Setup Nock
    nock(config.IDENTITY_URL)
      .post('/Token', { userName: 'xxx@xxx.com', password: 'xxxxx' })
      .reply(200, loginReply)

    // Start up the saga tester
    const sagaTester = new SagaTester({})

    sagaTester.start(loginSaga)

    // Dispatch the event to start the saga
    sagaTester.dispatch({type: types.LOGIN_REQUEST})

    // Hook into the success action
    await sagaTester.waitFor(types.LOGIN_SUCCESS)

    // Check the resulting action
    expect(sagaTester.getLatestCalledAction()).to.deep.equal({
      type: types.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: loginReply
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: do you how do generators work?

Comment: first time using them so still learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You received the following error : `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL` because you didn't call the `done` callback in your test.

Comment: did this answer solve the issue ? Its is not clear where you are supposed to call done(). Calling this way might prematurely return done().

Comment: You are supposed to call done() manually when you're not returning a promise inside your test.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have [specified a body](https://github.com/node-nock/nock#specifying-request-body) (`{ userName: 'xxx@xxx.com', password: 'xxxxx' }`) in your `nock` mocking, it won't respond `loginReply` until it gets a post request with both given URL and body. But you don't send `credentials` with your `LOGIN_REQUEST` action and hence your axios request body( `payload.data` ) is always going to be empty. That's why your `nock` mocking doesn't reply within specified async timeout and `jest` give this timeout error.

To fix this you either have to remove the specified body in your `nock` setup or dispatch `LOGIN_REQUEST` action with credentials and change the specified body to match encoded credentials you set to `payload`.

Comment: I removed the credentials from the nock but still getting same error